# Accessing and using data returned by SDL_QueryTexture() causes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to simply ascertain the width and height of a given texture.  `SDL_QueryTexture()` seems to return with no errors, but the moment I try at actually access and use the data, it segfaults.

When stepping through with the debugger this line causes the fault:

```
cout << "width is : " << *w << " height is : " << *h << endl;
```

Am I missing something here? Maybe I'm misinterpreting the documentation?

I'm using Netbeans on Windows with MinGW's compiler.

```
testCharacter = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 3, 5);

int* w;
int* h;
Uint32* format;
int* access;

if (SDL_QueryTexture(testCharacter, format, access, w, h) != 0) {
    cout << "ERROR : " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
} else {
    cout << "no error" << endl;
}

cout << "width is : " << *w << " height is : " << *h << endl;
```

Also the above code is the exact code that produces the error.

Comment: You have undefined behavior. `SDL_QueryTexture` expects certain arguments to be pointers to something so it can fill in the value but neither `format`, `access`,`w`, or `h` point to anything.

Comment: aah haa, yep that got it, I was misinterpreting ;-)

Comment: also how do I make your comment the answer?